Decode Complex MultiPart/Form-Data in Python
I am trying to decode the following object structure, which contains text data and file data in Python.
groupId: text
groupName: text
friendlyName: text
shortDescription: text
mainDescriptionList: [ {descriptionTitle: text, descriptionText: text } ]
imagesList: [ { imageTitle: text, file: File } ]
coordinatorList: [ { cordinatorName: text, file: File } ]

The following is how the console outputs the outgoing request to the lambda function.
groupId: 
groupName: AQQQ QWEJLER LELERLNE
friedlyName: 
shortDescription: Amdslkfn dlsfjs dsfkjdgsmd dsfjdsfsdf dljsdojjwe;'fgmfg v;ojdsf dsnfsdlkg;ldsm;sdjs/msdfjgfsd;.
mainDescriptionList[]: [object Object]
mainDescriptionList[]: [object Object]
imagesList[]: [object Object]
imagesList[]: [object Object]
eventList[]: [object Object]
eventList[]: [object Object]
coordinatorList[]: [object Object]
coordinatorList[]: [object Object]

In the Lambda function, I have written the following code to decode the incoming multipart/form-data from my ReactJS application. In the code I'm outputting the header and the content into CloudWatch log.
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    headers = event['headers']
    postData = base64.b64decode(event['body'])
    
    for part in decoder.MultipartDecoder(postData, headers['content-type']).parts:
        print(part.headers[b'Content-Disposition'].decode('utf-8'))
        print(part.text)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }

In the CloudWatch log it shows the following output;
form-data; name="groupName"
AQQQ QWEJLER LELERLNE

form-data; name="shortDescription"
Amdslkfn dlsfjs dsfkjdgsmd dsfjdsfsdf dljsdojjwe;'fgmfg v;ojdsf dsnfsdlkg;ldsm;sdjs/msdfjgfsd;.

form-data; name="mainDescriptionList[]"
[object Object]

form-data; name="mainDescriptionList[]"
[object Object]

form-data; name="imagesList[]"
[object Object]

form-data; name="imagesList[]"
[object Object]

form-data; name="eventList[]"
[object Object]

form-data; name="eventList[]"
[object Object]

form-data; name="coordinatorList[]"
[object Object]

form-data; name="coordinatorList[]"
[object Object]

I want to extract/decode the object type data, which contains in, mainDescriptionList, imagesList, eventList & coordinatorList. But struggling how I can achieve that in Python (v3.12).
Appreciate your help on this.
Update: I am using "requests_toolbelt" package in python for decoding the multipart/form-data
